Clinic scheduler design issue
anyone with experience in healthcare design could help me out here
so for last few days i’m pondering over the design requirements in a scheduler calendar for doctors.
The scheduler is for the clinic that manages doctors appointments.
So we have color coded for each doctors. The issue here is we need to show the patient type for each appointment but we icons are not to be used, as it is already alot.
I tried using patterns but could not find a good legible pattern
Anyone with any idea on how to present here?

How many is "a lot"? It is very different to design a coding for five individuals than for five hundred.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

can't u use tag or label for patients type?

My 2 bits

Color coding better be done on speciality or department, rather than each doctor so that the patient for that department/speciality need not be color coded.
You can use text based patient type, with secondary text color, either 60% black or lighter version of doctor's color code.

